# Differentiating the definite integral of x*f(x)

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm trying to differentiate the integral below. I was wondering how I could approach it.

z ~ N(a , $b^2$ $\cdot$ $x^{-2}$)

$\frac{d}{dx} \int _{-\infty} ^ {z^*(x)} z \cdot \Phi ^{\prime} (z) dz$

$z*=d \cdot x^{-2} $

where a, b & d are constants.

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

$=-\frac{d}{x^2} \cdot \Phi^{\prime}(\frac{d}{x^2}) \cdot \frac{-2d}{x^3}$

$=\frac{2d^2}{x^5} \cdot \Phi^{\prime}(\frac{d}{x^2})$